# Computer Won't Boot Properly, unless in safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I bought a computer today and booted it up, but when I did I only got a blank screen. I checked to make sure it wasn't the monitor by connecting it to my old computer...it worked. I then tried connecting my monitor to both DVI ports and found that the bottom one did work. However, now it just boots up and says "loading windows" and then when the login screen is suppose to come up the screen just goes blank and monitor says "no input, check cord" (or something like that).

I tried reinstalling windows and then I was able to log on normally. I used the CD's and reinstalled all the drivers, then rebooted...now I am stuck right back where I started. I tried taking out the RAM and inserting into different slots, that didn't fix anything. I was able to boot up into windows using safe-mode. I suspected that my ATI Radeon 6950 was the issue and downloaded the drivers, but I can't install them on safe-mode. Someone said to install C++ distr. and I tried doing that to fix driver installation problem of "failed to load detection driver" but it wouldn't let me do that either. Please someone help me, I don't want to have to deal with the evil redtape of sending it back to get a replacement!

[My computer](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883229236)

[Driver detection problem](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/hardwareheaven-tools-discussion/174912-failed-load-detection-driver-installation-error.html)

[Driver download page](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx#1)

I am using windows 7.

**Updates:**

1. Trying a 2nd reinstall of win7 to see if I can't get back in and try and install the updated drivers I downloaded. Upon running a system quality check it came back telling me I had a 1/7.9 rating for graphics. I don't think it is detecting it for some reason. Grrrr...
2. after reinstallation it seemed to work then it just restarted unexpectedly. I sucessfully logged back in and reinstalled the graphics card driver and rebooted. Resulted in going back to square one. Will not load login screen!?
3. Disabled the display adapter (e.g. my graphics card and it seems to boot up fine, regardless of resolution).
4. I kinda made my own solution a while back, just forgot about this question. I think there are issues with the AMD software that manages the video card, that is to say it is not very compatible with my monitor. I did trick my computer to think it was displaying on my old monitor and that worked until you rebooted the computer. There was an update to the AMD software and now it can reboot without totally resetting. It's still buggy and I have to readjust my monitor position and resolution after each reboot, but that's a bit of progress? lol

Comment: Trying a 2nd reinstall of win7 to see if I can't get back in and try and install the updated drivers I downloaded. Upon running a system quality check it came back telling me I had a 1/7.9 rating for graphics. I don't think it is detecting it for some reason. Grrrr...

Comment: after reinstallation it seemed to work then it just restarted unexpectedly. I sucessfully logged back in and reinstalled the graphics card driver and rebooted. Resulted in going back to square one. Will not load login screen!?

Comment: Disabled the display adapter (e.g. my graphics card and it seems to boot up fine, regardless of resolution).

Comment: those 3 comments are better suited as edits to your question. Could you add them as such please?

Comment: Can you go into more details about the "blank screen"?  Is your mouse visible?  Does alt+ctrl+del result in anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely your graphics card.
Telltale symptoms:

- WEI rating of 1, even with correct drivers installed
- Crash when switching to high resolution (from startup screens to login screen), successful bootup in low-resolution Safe Mode
- Successful boot with card disabled

You can try [baking it](http://www.overclock.net/t/623774/guide-total-noobs-guide-to-baking-a-gpu) to fix it, **but I would only recommend this as a last resort.**

Otherwise, unfortunately, you will need to get a new card. Since this is a new machine, you should be able to get it replaced under warranty.

Comment: I kinda made my own solution a while back, just forgot about this question. I think there are issues with the AMD software that manages the video card, that is to say it is not very compatible with my monitor. I did trick my computer to think it was displaying on my old monitor and that worked until you rebooted the computer. There was an update to the AMD software and now it can reboot without totally resetting. It's still buggy and I have to readjust my monitor position and resolution after each reboot, but that's a bit of progress? lol

Answer (score 0):

Appears to me to be a monitor resolution issue , try reducing the monitor resolution when you boot in the safe mode and restart

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try that as soon as I get home. Why exactly would that happen? I mean, if you spend 1,200 on a computer you would think it would be able to handle a higher resolution? Lets hope it is only that. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: A resolution issue is more likely to be reported as some form of "out of range" message on the monitor, rather than "no input, check cord".  But it varies from monitor to monitor, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just bought the computer, have you considered returning the computer to the retailer you bought if from?  Let them spend time and energy fixing a problem which is their responsibility, not yours.  They can either fix it, or replace it.

Comment: Well I thought I could learn from the process and I am expecting it to be a nasty process of repackaging, explaining and extra hidden fees, but I think that is what it is coming down to anyhow. I will call them tomorrow. Thanks.