# Starts to desktop background color, no start menu, unless in Safe Mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Similar, but likely not the same: [Computer Won't Boot Properly, unless in safe mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/258612/computer-wont-boot-properly-unless-in-safe-mode)

### Main issue description

When my PC starts up in Standard mode, it intermittently (about 20% of the time, at times much more or much less) starts to a green screen (my desktop background color).  The mouse cursor is visible.  alt+ctrl+del works.  I can bring up the task manager and start Chrome and other applications.  I often do so because I don't want to reset.

### Current workaround

Well, I can start into Safe Mode, and that works 100% of the time without ever producing this issue!  So, I'm hoping I can somehow use the Safe Mode configuration to ditch this issue?

### Other issues on this machine

["Connect to a network" does not open (and others)?](https://superuser.com/questions/777655/connect-to-a-network-does-not-open-and-others)

### System info

I'm on an HP 6530b.  Fresh Win 7 Pro SP1 install.  Now using default services.

### Major differences between Safe Mode and Standard ##

- Spybot and Zone Alarm run in Safe. **- UPDATE -** ZA and Spybot were uninstalled, to test them against these issues.
- Video drivers run in Safe.
- "Connect to a network" opens cleanly, every time, in Safe.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: Any way I can verify my system files against an online service and go for a fee default boot.ini, or borrow my safe mode boot.ini?

Comment: Actually, Windows 7 doesn't use `boot.ini` at all. If you want to check system files, open a command prompt as administrator and run the following command: `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Eventually, this slowed down, but it was never resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe the Explorer service failed to start on boot up for some reason. Try starting it manually from the command prompt or the "run"  dialog by pressing win+r.  If that works, make sure that service is in the list of startup services.

Comment: I use File->Run in the Task Manager to start explorer.exe.  Explorer is running when I get to it.  Ending and restarting it does not help.  I think it's a deeper issue.

Comment: It may have failed to start properly. Anyone have a healthy startup and shutdown script I can go through?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: switch from selective startup to normal startup in msconfig.